# Can the 0 vector be thought of as any point in space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The dimension of a subspace V of $ℝ^m$ can be considered as the cardinality of the basis of V.

When I think of 3 dimensions intuitively, I think of an infinite collection (speaking informally) of planes (2 dimensional subspace) stacked on top of each other.
Similarly with planes: they can be thought of as an infinite "collection" of lines (like $y = k$ where k belongs to the set of Reals) stacked on top of each other.

Going by this logic, a line is an infinite collection of points. Since a line is a 1 dimensional subspace, then a point can be considered to have 0 dimensions.

Also, the sum of the vectors of the basis of a subspace can also be considered to have the same dimensions of the subspace itself. For example, the vector sum of 3 linearly independent vectors in $R^3$ will be 3 dimensional.

Since the dimension of {0 vector} is 0, and this subspace contains only the 0 vector, it can be safe to say that the 0 vector has 0 dimensions. And since we know now that 0 dimensions can be thought of as a point, can we not claim the 0 vector to be the origin?

And because we can "move" vectors around without changing their direction or magnitude, can we not also say that the 0 vector could be considered to be any point in space at all? I am asking this here because I want to know where my logic is going wrong, if at all.

Comment: Every subspace passes through $0$

Comment: "*can we not also say that the 0* ***vector*** *could be considered to be any* ***point*** *in space*" $\;-\;$ A vector is not a point. You'll need to clarify what association you have in mind between points and vectors.

Comment: As long as you can visualize the vector space, you can think a vector as an arrow from the origin to the point representing the vector.

Comment: @SouravGhosh so an arrow from the origin to the origin itself is just a point, is it not?

Comment: @dxiv the association is that they are both 0 dimensional subspaces. (The association between the 0 vector and a point, not just any vector)

Comment: An element of a vector space is called a vector. Even a matrix can be a vector, a function can be vector.